# How to avoid hanging the Mac Pro

Tags: mac

I have a macbook pro 13 inch, early 2011 model, with 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3.

I use this laptop basically for browsing , microsoft word and other basic functions.
The laptop is getting really stuck repeatedly for the last 2 months.

I'm searching any hint about the reasons, the way to find them and to speed up again the computer.

Comment: What does 'really stuck' mean? Long delays? Full crashes? What are the symtoms or error codes. Without those there simply is not enough information to give a decent answer.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate, and no more clear than, http://superuser.com/questions/969937/how-to-speed-up-macbook-pro-recently-slowed-down

Comment: Stuck means, If i open a browser, Its take long time to  open and everytime it takes some time to open the application even notepad and word

Comment: @Mohaideen - How many tabs do you have open?  The type of behavior you describe, often is linked to an OS waiting on I/O events to happen, the typical cause of that is a HDD that is starting to fail.

Comment: Leave about Browsers. Same problem on word and notepad also. I have checked all the possibilities. That means, memory is there, 4GB Ram. But still getting slow

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Open Activity Monitor -> are there any processes hugging the CPU in the CPU view? How is memory pressure (in the memory view)?